# In MySQL check if set of values is equal to the values of another set; don't care about order

Tags: mysql

I'm checking if 2 foreign ids of a table are equal to 2 foreign keys in another table to the same table, but I don't care about the order of the ids, just that they have the same values.

i.e.

```
SELECT (1, 2, 3) = (1, 2, 3);
> 1

SELECT (1, 2, 3) = (2, 1, 3);
> 0
```

I'd like a way so that `(1,2,3)` matches `(2,1,3)` as well as `(1,3,2)` and `(2,3,1)`.

Unfortunately searching for information on this has proved difficult, most advice is "Lists don't exist in MySQL" and searches for sorting, or unordered checking result in various SQL calls that aren't relevant.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqz27tR9uDMQriDhkwBo2a/0

I deliberately put an `event` in the table with the participants ordered differently to the participants in `not_event`, and it's that join,

```
SELECT * FROM event
 JOIN not_event ON (
  (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id) =
  (not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id));
```

That's the issue.  I don't care what order `participant_1_id` and `participant_2_id` are, in either table, so long as they're the same 2.

Rest of code from fiddle,

```
CREATE TABLE `participant` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `participant_1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `participant_2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_1_id`) REFERENCES `participant` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_2_id`) REFERENCES `participant` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `not_event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `participant_1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `participant_2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `not_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_1_id`) REFERENCES `participant` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `not_event_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`participant_2_id`) REFERENCES `participant` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `participant` VALUES (1, 'Team1');
INSERT INTO `participant` VALUES (2, 'Team2');

INSERT INTO `event` VALUES (NULL, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO `not_event` VALUES (NULL, 2, 1);

SELECT (1, 2, 3) = (1, 2, 3);
SELECT (1, 2, 3) = (2, 1, 3);

SELECT * FROM event
 JOIN not_event ON (
 (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id) =
 (not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id));


SELECT * FROM event
 JOIN not_event ON (
 (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id) =
 (not_event.participant_2_id, not_event.participant_1_id));
```

Comment: Are you saying that `(1, 2, 3)` are not all values of the same column? `1` is the value of one column, `2` is the value of a different column, and so on?

Comment: Can you show some sample table data and the desired result?

Comment: Note to OP. stay calm and just flag things that are upsetting you. The mods will deal with it.

Comment: @Barmar, I've added the sample code of the `event` table, it has 2 foreign key columns linking to 2 different rows in the `participant` table.  I'm connecting another table (here `not_event`) which also links to 2 different rows of the `participant` table, but there's no guarantee that they'll be in the same "order", as in participant_1 of `event` could be participant_2 of `not_event`, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found you can achieve this via 3 different methods.  1 is querying the `event` and `not_event` tables, and joining the `participant` table twice, grouping them together, and running a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` comparing `GROUP_CONCAT`s,

```
SELECT event.*, not_event.*
 FROM event
 JOIN participant p1 ON p1.id IN (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id),
 not_event
 JOIN participant p2 ON p2.id IN (not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id)

 GROUP BY event.id, not_event.id
 HAVING 
    GROUP_CONCAT(p1.key ORDER BY p1.key) = 
    GROUP_CONCAT(p2.key ORDER BY p2.key)
```

Or by running 2 subqueries that do `GROUP_CONCAT` on the field that you're interested in joining them on, and then join them afterwards,

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(participant.id ORDER BY participant.id) `key`, event.*
 FROM event
 JOIN participant ON (participant.id IN (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id))
 GROUP BY event.id) _event

JOIN (
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(participant.id ORDER BY participant.id) `key`, not_event.*
 FROM not_event
 JOIN participant ON (participant.id IN (not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id))
 GROUP BY not_event.id) _not_event

ON _event.key = _not_event.key;
```

And then the super "direct" or manual way,

```
 SELECT event.*, not_event.*
 FROM event, not_event

 WHERE
    event.participant_1_id IN (not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id) AND 
    event.participant_2_id IN (not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id) AND 
    not_event.participant_1_id IN (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id) AND 
    not_event.participant_2_id IN (event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id)
```

These all join them correctly as wanted.

Updated fiddle: 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqz27tR9uDMQriDhkwBo2a/5

With both solutions, `Event(1, 2)` correctly joins with `NotEvent(2, 1)` and nothing else, and `Event(2, 3)` correctly joins with `NotEvent(3, 2)` and nothing else.

I *still* think it's crazy that you have to join a table like this, in this way, rather than just comparing the keys within the table directly, but these work, one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

A few options, none I'm really happy with,

For binary joins, with only 2 fields, using `LEAST` and `GREATEST` works, but on more than 2 fields, it wouldn't work,

```
SELECT * FROM event
 JOIN not_event ON (
  LEAST(event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id) =
  LEAST(not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id)
   AND
  GREATEST(event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id) =
  GREATEST(not_event.participant_1_id, not_event.participant_2_id));
```

After that, there seems to be a dreadfully inefficient `LENGTH` check, with multiple `REPLACE`s with `CONCAT_WS`,

```
SELECT * FROM event
 JOIN not_event ON (
 1 = LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(
   CONCAT_WS(
     ',', event.participant_1_id, event.participant_2_id),
   not_event.participant_1_id, ''), not_event.participant_2_id, ''))
 );
```

But this one sucks, and is unreliable, because "1" would replace "11" with "", "2" replaces "222" with "", etc.

Updated fiddle (with these solutions): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eqz27tR9uDMQriDhkwBo2a/1

Comment: To the question (well phrased) and answer (helpful at times) +1; but I think the original problem here is the table structure.  You really should normalize your tables. When you are creating multiple columns to represent nth value of similar things; it is going to be problematic. Instead you should simply have one column to represent participant_id; with multiple rows representing different participants

Comment: I don't think there can be more normalisation, this is a sports event table, with two participants, generally a team at home, and a team away. What else can be normalised? And I'm migrating data from an old/legacy table.

Comment: Madhur Bhalya, please get back to me on what should be more normalised here, or remove your comment. You're comment is about the 4th reference to normalisation, without a single suggestion about how to normalise the table I have. This question is nothing to do with normalisation, it's about comparing two set of values in MySQL. I only provided a sample table, with sample data because it was requested. The question though is still *only* about comparing two sets of values.

Comment: Please read "Instead you should simply have one column to represent participant_id; with multiple rows representing different participants" in my first comment. This is normally achieved via a mapping table, such as `event_to_participant`, which shall contain `(event_id, participant_id)`

Comment: Yeah, for this purpose, I'm dealing with millions of events, of multiple sports types, with 2 participants per event.  Having 1 table with p_1_id and p_2_id (and competition_id, and date) is degrees more efficient than having a mish-mash with two tables. *If* there were a variable amount of participants, I'd go the multiple table route, but would affect performance quite a bit (I've been that route already).